# Automatic Core Data Migration if I have a few mappings between source and destination stores?

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

Suppose I have store with model version A, application is published in AppStore.
Then I added new model version B, updated some entity (added new attribute with some converting from old attribute), added mapping model, where I set value expression for new attribute like this `FUNCTION($entityPolicy, "convertOldToNew:" , $source)` and set appropriate `NSEntityMigrationPolicy` subclass name (`convertOldToNew:` is implemented).

At a later time I added new model version C with new converting rules (new mapping from B to C, new `NSEntityMigrationPolicy` subclass).

When I setup `NSPersistentStoreCoordinater`, I use options:

```
@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES,NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES}.
```

Migration works, if store is updated after each application update (when application with model B is published, all users update it and initiate migration; when model C is published, all users should have application with version B store). But if app has store with version A, and it is updated to version C, migration doesn't work. I thought CoreData can handle all available mappings from version to version, but it doesn't do it.

My question is, how should I handle this case? When I publish new model version, should I add mappings to support all previous versions (if I have versions from 1 to 5, I will have 10 different mappings)?

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

1) If migration is needed

```
+ (NSDictionary *)metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:(NSString *)storeType URL:(NSURL *)url error:(NSError **)error    
- (BOOL)isConfiguration:(NSString *)configuration compatibleWithStoreMetadata:(NSDictionary *)metadata
```

I copy original store (sqlite, sqlite-wal, sqlite-shm) to temp files.

2) Start migration loop. I get `NSManagedObjectModel` for current store (in temp file), read next version name from its "versionIdentifiers" property, create next version object `NSManagedObjectModel`, load mapping:

```
+ (NSMappingModel *)mappingModelFromBundles:(NSArray *)bundles forSourceModel:(NSManagedObjectModel *)sourceModel destinationModel:(NSManagedObjectModel *)destinationModel
```

if mapping is not found, try to generate mapping:

```
+ (NSMappingModel *)inferredMappingModelForSourceModel:(NSManagedObjectModel *)sourceModel destinationModel:(NSManagedObjectModel *)destinationModel error:(NSError **)error
```

and use it in migration manager:

```
- (instancetype)initWithSourceModel:(NSManagedObjectModel *)sourceModel destinationModel:(NSManagedObjectModel *)destinationModel
- (BOOL)migrateStoreFromURL:(NSURL *)sourceURL type:(NSString *)sStoreType options:(NSDictionary *)sOptions withMappingModel:(NSMappingModel *)mappings toDestinationURL:(NSURL *)dURL destinationType:(NSString *)dStoreType destinationOptions:(NSDictionary *)dOptions error:(NSError **)error
```

In each iteration I delete previous temp store and start using new one. When next `NSManagedObjectModel` is not found, I stop loop and replace original store with the latest temp one (compatible with the latest `NSManagedObjectModel` version).

**In each `NSManagedObjectModel` version in Xcode I set previous and next version info in `versionIdentifiers` property, so I can load appropriate model object at runtime**